# CSS wait till parent transition is finished then instantly transition child

Tags: html, css

I have a situation like the following

```css
.parent {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 25px;
  background-color: grey;
  
  transition: width 0.25s;
}

.parent:hover {
  width: 300px;
}

.child {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<h3>Hover Over</h3>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

I need have the child stay at the same width until the parent is completed its transition.

I know that this is possible with absolute styles. See the snippet below:

```css
.parent {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 25px;
  background-color: grey;

  transition: width 0.25s;
}

.parent:hover {
  width: 300px;
}

.child {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}

.parent:hover .child {
  width: 300px;
  
  transition-delay: 0.25s;
}
```

```html
<h3>Hover Over</h3>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

The current element that I need this for is has relative styles (`100%`) so the snippet above wouldn't work in my case. Is there a way to change the snippet above to work with relative styles or is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add same transition to child class. Take A look below:

```css
.parent {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 25px;
  background-color: grey;

  transition: width 0.25s;
}

.parent:hover {
  width: 300px;
}

.child {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  transition: width 0.25s;
}

.parent:hover .child {
  width: 300px;
  
  transition-delay: 0.25s;
}
```

```html
<h3>Hover Over</h3>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

If you have to say that `.child` will have the width of 100%, so it will really have follow the width of its parent no matter what width it is. To make it have a delay transition, the `.child` should have a starting width then. But if you have to insist on having the child a 100% width, is it possible if you can use JS/JQuery? If that so, check the snippet I have below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var width = $('.child').width();
  
  $('.child').css({
    'width': width
  });
  
  $('.parent').hover(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('.child').css({
        'width': 'calc(100%)'
      })
    }, 500)
  }, function() {
    $('.child').css({
      'width': width
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.parent {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 25px;
  background-color: grey;
  transition: width 0.25s;
}

.parent:hover {
  width: 300px;
}

.child {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  transition: .2s width 0.25s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Hover Over</h3>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I need what I have in the snippent in my answer that works, but using `100%` width on the child instead of `200px` for the `width`

Comment: Please take a look at my updated answer if that will answer your problem.

Answer (score 1):

It is actually possible with only CSS, although this is a bit of a dirty method.
If you change the `font-size` to some `number [px|em|etc.]` instead of the `width` property, this will enable the size of both to change "independently".

The drawback of this method is that you will need to add another child element (or `::before | ::after`) with a more reasonable `font-size` if you want to display some text inside these elements, so it might be better for your purpose to use some JS like @jmc but if you can't (or don't want to :p) this might be the solution for you.

```css
.parent {
  font-size: 200px;
  width: 1em;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 25px;
  background-color: grey;
  
  transition: width 0.25s;
}

.parent:hover {
  font-size: 300px;
}

.child {
  width: 1em;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  
  transition: width 0.25s;
}

.child:hover, .parent:hover > .child {
  transition: width 0.25s 0.25s linear;
}
```

```html
<h3>Hover Over</h3>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```